# When building with grunt how/what do I deploy to my tomcat server?

Tags: javascript, tomcat, backbone.js, deployment, gruntjs

I guess I'm used to using something like ant or maven that produces a war file and I deploy that war file to my server.

With grunt I don't see what I'm supposed to deploy.  Am I supposed to grab the public dir and cut and paste?

I am using Backbone-Requires-Boilerplate it supplies the grunt file.  I use the grunt command and it executes without errors.  I'm just at a loss on what to do next.

Any suggestions?

Thanks,

Andrew

Comment: use codeship.io and grunt task to deploy - so basically, your grunt file will build your project and launch node or whatever engine you are running and codeship.io will watch your repo, pull your repo to your server and run your grunt task

Comment: @imrane codeship.io looks promissing down the road.  I'm looking for a more scaled back DIY solution currently.

Comment: I think my choice is going to be "use maven".  It can create a war with just my js front end and I know how to deploy that already.  I am just so impressed with the javascript opensource community that I figured someone would have created something to fit that part of the production chain.

Comment: people are using grunt-shell - https://github.com/sindresorhus/grunt-shell - ...http://jpetersson.se/#!/post/using-grunt-js-as-deployment-tool

Comment: This seems to be a very robust article on deploying javascript application. (http://alexsexton.com/blog/2013/03/deploying-javascript-applications/) It includes a grunt.js plugin to deploy your static content an S3 CDN.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

"grunt-tomcat-deploy" plugin build a war and publish over the Tomcat Admin Web Application.

https://npmjs.org/package/grunt-tomcat-deploy

Answer (score 3):

You can use the "[grunt-war](https://www.npmjs.com/package/grunt-war)" plugin to build the war (no maven or ant required for war assembly).

Side note:

The "grunt-tomcat-deploy" looks like it can deploy the war remotely (http) to tomcat but there was no mention in the docs about what version(s) of tomcat it supports. It might even be able to build the war that you need.  I looked at the source code and it's war assembly is not very flexible but it might be a 1 stop shop for your needs.

Comment: I also use grunt-war for my front end project, it is easy to use. Good project.